# Augmented triads in classical music

Tags: chords, harmony, classical-music

I would like to know of examples of augmented chords of type 5# (I do not refer to 6th) in classical music, I know the theory for the formation of this type of chords (C aug or C+ or C(5#)-> C, 3ª major interval -> E and 5ª augmented interval -> G#), I have learned many examples in popular music and jazz but I would like to know in as much detail as possible examples in classical music.

Comment: Definitely check out some of Debussy's work.  He did some compositions that focus entirely on the Whole Tone scale, which can only create triads of the augmented type.  There's also this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pieces_which_use_the_whole_tone_scale

Comment: Ok, if you know more examples write here, I will try to study them all. And many thanks to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I start, note that oftentimes these "augmented triads" in classical music are not *bonafide* augmented triads but actually just dominants with a brief chromatic passing tone. But not always!

Now, there's really no better one-stop shop than [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W20E_-S6U0c) terrific minuet by Mozart (K 355). [Here's](http://ks.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/3/38/IMSLP56685-PMLP116912-Mozart_Werke_Breitkopf_Serie_22_KV355.pdf) a score, and below is a sample of the opening measures; check out the augmented triads in mm. 1, 5, 7, and 9. (Whether they truly "are" and function as augmented triads is a much longer discussion; but they do momentarily create augmented harmonies.)

[image]

And since I've got Wagner on the brain, here are some other ideas.

I've linked the music; I'll leave it up to you to find the scores:

- Wagner, *Siegfried*, Act I Scene 3 (beginning in m. 2430), at the famous ["Nothung!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwP5dkfGmlI) calls. The calls themselves are above an F augmented triad, and there's a brief intro that could be understood as a D augmented triad.
- Wagner, *Siegfried*, Act III Scene 2 (m. 440), as [Siegfried confronts The Wanderer](https://youtu.be/uOjBYl7l1qw?t=17m45s). The opening progression, in A flat, alternates between I and V+.
- Similarly, check out Beethoven's Op. 119 No. 1 Bagatelle in G minor. In m. 17, a V chord in A flat has a chromatic passing tone B-natural that briefly creates a V+.

Comment: I would analyize MM. 5, 7, 9 differently. The "augmented triad" is just an written-out appoggiatura before a Bm/D chord (in M.5) followed by an augmented 6th and C# (again, with a written-out appoggiatura). As for MM. 1 and 2, I would call that "counterpoint" not "harmony." The harmonic progression is just D A7. The Wagner example is unambiguous, though.

Comment: I agree 100%; I tried to hint at this in the parenthesized section of my second paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, I read it too fast and thought you meant a *bona fide* example of *augmented* triads, not *ambiguous* ones!

Comment: I tried to make it a bit clearer, in any event!

Comment: I so glad this post reappeared with recent activity, because I discovered this K355 in your answer. I never heard it before. What a great example of harmony! I analyzed the whole thing last night. I will post a new question about one particular part that confused me. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will find plenty of augmented chords in the music of Edvard Grieg.  For instance, Measures 11 and 13 of "To Spring", Op. 43 no. 6.
[image: Grieg: "To Spring", measures 10 through 14]

Answer (score 3):

Beethoven actually uses them quite functionally in the first movement of Eroica, right in the beginning of the development. Here, the Ab augmented triad resolves into G7 with Ab moving down to G and E natural up to F. Then with the same melody he moves from C major to F minor, then again from Ab augmented to G7, where he stays for four bars before modulating to G major, using the Ab major chord as a Neapolitan.

[image: Beginning of development from Liszt's transcription]

Comment: What are your thoughts on that E-natural just being a lower neighbor tone to the F, and this chord being a `iv6` instead of A-flat augmented?

Answer (score 1):

Mozart used augmented triads in his sonata in A major (3rd variation for example).
Chopin used augmented triads in his prelude in e minor (augmented triad with a major 7th)
and a full augmented triad in his prelude in c minor.